# How to debug a grid by using OpenSeaDragon

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a grid with multiple lines and multiple columns for a image by using 
[OpenSeaDragon](http://openseadragon.github.io/docs/symbols/OpenSeadragon.OsmTileSource.html)

In the official debug mode, they have multiple rows and columns for the grid;

How can I set my grid to have multiple rows and columns?

example [here](http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/developer-debug-mode/)

my page looks like [this](http://content.screencast.com/users/flaviuspogacian/folders/Jing/media/dada7518-4061-42f6-b7f3-a443f9e38a36/2013-09-12_1746.png)

ps: If you know something better, please let me know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>open sea dragon</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' 
          type='text/css'
          media='screen'
          href='./css/style.css'/>

    <script src="./openseadragon.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demoarea">
    <div id="contentDiv" class="openseadragon"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Example
    OpenSeadragon({
        id:              "contentDiv",
        prefixUrl:       "./images/",
        tileSources:     "./highsmith.dzi",
        debugMode:  true,
        showNavigator:  true,
        navigatorPosition:   "TOP_RIGHT",
        OsmTileSource: {'width':10,'height':10,'tileSize':10,'tileOverlap':10}
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```